# How to receive the facebook graph api returned data?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am new to stackoverflow and programming. I am just learing php and decided to work with facebook place search api for just practice purpose.

I have written the below code in php:

```
$FacebookGraphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.$keyword.'&type=place' . htmlentities('&center=') .$center.'&distance='.$distance.'&access_token='.ACCESS_TOKEN;

$FacebookGraphJSON = @file_get_contents($FacebookGraphURL);
$dataArray = json_decode($FacebookGraphJSON);
```

But it don't return anything. I think this is not appropriate way to get from graph api.I have searched quite a lot but could not find one which I can understand as I am a novice.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `htmlentities('&center=') .$center` should be `&center=' . htmlentities($center) .`

2) don't use the @ before `file_get_contents` this will suppress error (warning in this case) when your file request fails.

try the code below:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN','**********************************************');
$keyword = 'coffee';
$center= urlencode('37.76,-122.427');
$distance=1000;
$FacebookGraphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.$keyword.'&type=place&center='.$center.'&distance='.$distance.'&access_token='.ACCESS_TOKEN;
$FacebookGraphJSON = file_get_contents($FacebookGraphURL);
$dataArray = json_decode($FacebookGraphJSON);
var_dump($dataArray);
exit;
```

Comment: it's not working. given the below error:

[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in

Comment: you need to add an access_token in the line `define('ACCESS_TOKEN'`. See also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/: All Graph API search queries require an access token passed in with the access_token=<token> parameter. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.